# Error Saving Data to Postgres with Flask / SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a very simple Flask application with a user model. The model looks like this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    phone_number = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    # One-to-many relationship between users and dreams
    dreams = db.relationship('Dream', backref='user', lazy=True)

    def __init__(self, phone_number):
       self.phone_number = phone_number
```

I can query the database just fine, but when I'm inserting a new user into the model like this:

```
user = User(phone_number=phone_number)
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

I get this error:
`sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "id" of relation "users" violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, +16095555555).`

Which is strange because In the past when I've used SQLAlchemy it generally handles the id for me without it needing to be set manually. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Why do you have an explicit `__init__` method ? Why not use the one provided by inherting `db.Model` ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was missing this line which auto-generate id using a sequence in id column default expression:

```
nextval('table_id_seq'::regclass)
```